# how to select branch and revision number in jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I can able to pick branch or revision number during the build initialization using git parameter plugin. Is there any other way to select both at a time. I want to deploy old revision from particular branch.

Comment: You can probably use the API to get it if you know the build number

Comment: Rik, thank you for your suggestion. But my requirement is like first tab select the branch, once i selected the branch it should show list of revisions atleast latest 10. I have to select from that

Comment: You can just checkout a specific commit hash. Or is that not what you want? Maybe make your question. Little bit more explicit